# Shell script to compare

Tags: shell, awk

I have a shell script that reads two files which is basically an "ls" output in the following format

```
File 1 (Server1.txt):
386030    8 -rw-r--r--   1 bfdeploy wasgroup     4809 Jul 15 15:50 /apps/ibm/httpserver/htdocs/wp/en_robohelp/createFamilyAssessment.htm
386044    8 -rw-r--r--   1 bfdeploy wasgroup     6041 Jul 15 15:50 /apps/ibm/httpserver/htdocs/wp/en_robohelp/disabilityBenefits.htm
386179    8 -rw-r--r--   1 bfdeploy wasgroup     6780 Jul 15 15:50 /apps/ibm/httpserver/htdocs/wp/en_robohelp/staffSummaryAlerts.htm

File 2 (Server2.txt):
386030    8 -rw-r--r--   1 bfdeploy wasgroup     4809 Jul 15 15:50 /apps/ibm/httpserver/htdocs/wp/en_robohelp/createFamilyAssessment.htm
386044    8 -rw-r--r--   1 bfdeploy wasgroup     6041 Jul 15 15:50 /apps/ibm/httpserver/htdocs/wp/en_robohelp/disabilityBenefits.htm
386179    8 -rw-r--r--   1 bfdeploy wasgroup     6780 Jul 15 15:50 /apps/ibm/httpserver/htdocs/wp/en_robohelp/staffSummaryAlerts.htm
```

Using basic awk statements, I am trying to compare the filepermission (column 3); size (column 7); and filename (column 11) as follows, but it is printing even lines that are similar

```
while read line
    do
            filename1=$(echo "$line"|awk '{print $11}')
            filesize1=$(echo "$line"|awk '{print $7}')
            filepermission1=$(echo "$line"|awk '{print $3}')
            lineinserver2=$(grep "$filename1" "$SERVER2.txt")
            if [ $? -eq 1 ]
            then
                    echo "$filename1 is in $SERVER1 $COMPDIR but not present in $SERVER2 $COMPDIR" >> $DIFFSUMMARYFILE
            else
                    filesize2=$(echo "$lineinserver2"|awk '{print $7}')
            #       echo $lineinserver2
            #       echo $filesize2
                    filepermission2=$(echo "$lineinserver2"|awk '{print $3}')
            #       echo $filepermission2
                    if [ $filesize1 != $filesize2 ]
                    then
                            echo "$filename1 on $SERVER1 has a size of $filesize1 and on $SERVER2 has a size of $filesize2" >> $DIFFSUMMARYFILE
                    fi
                    if [ "$filepermission1" != "$filepermission2" ]
                    then
                            echo "$filename1 on $SERVER1 has permission of $filepermission1 and on $SERVER2 has permission of $filepermission2" >> $DIFFSUMMARYFILE
                    fi

            fi
    done < "$SERVER1.txt"
```

Based on Janos, comment I have updated the script as follows

```
 while read filepermission1 fileseize1 filename1; do
            read filepermission2 filesize2 filename2 < <(grep "$filename1" "$SERVER2.txt" | awk '{print $3, $7, $11}')
            if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
                    echo "$filename1 is in $SERVER1 $COMPDIR but not present in $SERVER2 $COMPDIR" >> $DIFFSUMMARYFILE
            else
                    if [ $filesize1 != $filesize2 ]; then
                    echo "$filename1 on $SERVER1 has a size of $filesize1 and $filename2 on $SERVER2 has a size of $filesize2" >> $DIFFSUMMARYFILE
                    fi
                    if [ "$filepermission1" != "$filepermission2" ]; then
                    echo "$filename1 on $SERVER1 has a permission of $filepermission1 and $filename2 on $SERVER2 has a permission of $filepermission2" >> $DIFFSUMMARYFILE
                    fi
            fi
    done < <(grep -xvf $SERVER2.txt $SERVER1.txt|awk '{print $3, $7, $11}')
```

Comment: In your sample, `Server1.txt` and `Server2.txt` are identical, so the script outputs nothing. I made modifications to trigger the summary lines and it worked correctly for all 3 cases: different permission or size or missing file. So what is the problem here?

Comment: @janos, All i changed was :  if [ ! "$lineserver2" ] . Then i create two files called test.txt in the two separate servers with different sizes. The script said this file was present on SERVER1 but not SERVER2. Hence my confusion.

Comment: Show some actually sample input (maybe 6 to 10 lines) and expected output otherwise we're just guessing. All we can tell so far for sure is that the approach you are taking is 100% wrong.

Comment: @FatOwl I rolled back your recent edits removing the script and input files. Questions on SO are a community resource; removing this information makes the question useless to anyone running across it in the future. If you want to remove the information from your `ls` output, replace it with dummy data that interacts with your script in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Your script seems to work for me as it is:

- If the sample files are identical, it outputs nothing, correctly
- If a filesize is different, it reports it correctly
- If a permission is different, it reports it correctly
- If a file is missing in the second file, it reports it correctly

To see more clearly, I rewrote it more efficiently, using modern bash constructs:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER1=server1
SERVER2=server2
while IFS=' ' read filepermission1 filesize1 filename1; do
    IFS=' ' read filepermission2 filesize2 filename2 < <(grep "$filename1" "$SERVER2.txt" | awk '{print $3, $7, $11}')
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "$filename1 is in $SERVER1 $COMPDIR but not present in $SERVER2 $COMPDIR"
    else
        if [ $filesize1 != $filesize2 ]; then
            echo "$filename1 on $SERVER1 has a size of $filesize1 and on $SERVER2 has a size of $filesize2"
        fi
        if [ "$filepermission1" != "$filepermission2" ]; then
            echo "$filename1 on $SERVER1 has permission of $filepermission1 and on $SERVER2 has permission of $filepermission2"
        fi
    fi
done < <(grep -vxf $SERVER2.txt $SERVER1.txt | awk '{print $3, $7, $11}')
```

**UPDATE**

From your comment, it seems the columns are not where you expect them to be. To see clearer, run with just `echo` lines, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER1=server1
SERVER2=server2
while read filepermission1 filesize1 filename1; do
    read filepermission2 filesize2 filename2 < <(grep "$filename1" "$SERVER2.txt" | awk '{print $3, $7, $11}')
    echo filepermission1=$filepermission1
    echo filesize1=$filesize1
    echo filename1=$filename1
    echo filepermission2=$filepermission2
    echo filesize2=$filesize2
    echo filename2=$filename2
done < <(grep -vxf $SERVER2.txt $SERVER1.txt | awk '{print $3, $7, $11}')
```

I hope that based on the output you should see clearer.

**CONCLUSION**

It seems the problem was due to `IFS=...` manipulation in the original script or in a calling script. As a workaround I inserted `IFS=' '` in front of the `read` commands, where it was important. Ideally the calling scripts should be changed to use `IFS='...' cmd`, so that the `IFS` manipulation will only be effective for `cmd` only. Then the `IFS=' '` in the above script can be safely removed, as the script should work fine with the default value.

Comment: Thank you very much. The requirement was to see only what is on server 1 but not on server 2 and not to check the other way around. Hence I did not do the second pass. I will make the above changes and let you know how it goes.

Comment: with the change you suggested, even though the file exists in server2, it is not finding it.

Comment: I don't believe your `$?` assignment statement is accurate. See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8152563 for example.

Comment: @janos I rewrote the script to mimic exactly what you have but am getting the results with no values eg:  on <server1> has a permission of -rw-r--r-- 52428800 /tmp/javasharedresources/C240D2A64P_webspherev70_wasgroup_G08 and  on <server1>has a permission of -rwxr-xr-x
 512 /tmp/IBM_LaunchPad_19802/callback.sh

Comment: Also, could you tell me what the $? should be?

Comment: @FatOwl it seems the columns are not where you expect them to be, somehow... See my updated answer, I hope it will help debugging it.

Comment: @Janos, looks like each variable is getting the whole line.. eg-rwxrwxrwx 0 /tmp/.com_ibm_tools_attach/_notifier

Comment: @Janos, the columns are in the right place.. but each variable is getting $3, $5 and $11

Comment: That can happen if you set the `IFS` shell variable to something. Are you sure your script or one of its caller scripts is not manipulating the value of the `IFS` variable?

Comment: @Janos, good point, I am reading a comma separated config file and hence have IFS="," set. This loop I pasted above happens while the config file is being read. Is there a way to overwrite this?

Comment: @FatOwl I updated my answer: I inserted `IFS=' '` right before the `read` commands. Btw if you run commands this way: `IFS='...' cmd` then the setting of `IFS` will only be effective for `cmd`, and that way you can eliminate side effects. So I recommend to change your calling scripts, thereby leaving `IFS` at its default value, and then you don't need insert the `IFS=' '` in this script, as it would work fine with the default.

Comment: Perfect. This works great. Hopefully my last question.. I am seeing the size and permission showing up for a file that is missing on server2 eg: the LaunchPad2820 directory does not even exist
/tmp/IBM_LaunchPad_2820/changeDirectory.sh on <server1>has a size of 381 and  on <server2>has a size of
/tmp/IBM_LaunchPad_2820/changeDirectory.sh on <server1>has a permission of -rwxr-xr-x and  on <server2>has a permission of

Comment: Strange. It works for me. If you're not using my script exactly, it could be another side effect. In the worst case, you could add extra checks in the `if [ $? -eq 1 ]` for example like this: `if [ $? -eq 1 -o ! "$filesize2" ]` but it would be really best to clean up your script and eliminate side effects.